# Spring MVC Form not taking object path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Error shown is **Bean property 'emergencyComplaint.emergencyComplaint' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?**

The getters and setters have the same return type, still it is showing this error.

JSP Page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>CRS | Kolkata</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Lodge an Emergency Complaint Now</h1>
            <form:form action="" method="post" modelAttribute="people">
                <form:label
                    path="emergencyComplaint.emergencyComplaint"
                    for="emergencyComplaint"
                >
                    Emergency Complaint
                </form:label>
                <form:input
                    type="text"
                    name="emergencyComplaint"
                    id="emergencyComplaint"
                    path="emergencyComplaint.emergencyComplaint"
                />

                <form:label
                    path="emergencyComplaint.status"
                    for="emergencyComplaintStatus"
                    >Status</form:label
                >

                <form:input
                    type="text"
                    name="emergencyComplaintStatus"
                    id="emergencyComplaintStatus"
                    path="emergencyComplaint.status"
                ></form:input>

                <form:label path="name" for="name">Name</form:label>
                <form:input path="name" type="text" name="name" id="name" />

                <form:label path="phoneNumber" for="phoneNumber"
                    >Phone Number</form:label
                >
                <form:input
                    path="phoneNumber"
                    type="text"
                    name="phoneNumber"
                    id="phoneNumber"
                />

                <button type="submit">Lodge</button>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Model Class

```
package com.naha.crimereportingsystem.people;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import com.naha.crimereportingsystem.emergencyComplaint.EmergencyComplaint;

@Entity
public class People {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = EmergencyComplaint.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EmergencyComplaint> emergencyComplaint;

    public People() {

    }

    public People(long id, String name, String phoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.emergencyComplaint = (List<EmergencyComplaint>) new EmergencyComplaint();
    }

    public List<EmergencyComplaint> getEmergencyComplaint() {
        return emergencyComplaint;
    }

    public void setEmergencyComplaint(List<EmergencyComplaint> emergencyComplaint) {
        this.emergencyComplaint = emergencyComplaint;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Mapped Other Model Class

```
package com.naha.crimereportingsystem.emergencyComplaint;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class EmergencyComplaint {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;
    private String emergencyComplaint;
    private String status;

    public String getEmergencyComplaint() {
        return emergencyComplaint;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setEmergencyComplaint(String emergencyComplaint) {
        this.emergencyComplaint = emergencyComplaint;
    }

    public EmergencyComplaint(long id, String emergencyComplaint, String status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.emergencyComplaint = emergencyComplaint;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public EmergencyComplaint(String emergencyComplaint, String status) {
        this.emergencyComplaint = emergencyComplaint;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public EmergencyComplaint() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid error. Take a close look at your Entity and your modelAttribute. There is no such thing **emergencyComplaint.emergencyComplaint**.

So, instead of:

```
<form:input type="text" name="emergencyComplaint" id="emergencyComplaint" path="emergencyComplaint.emergencyComplaint" />
```

Try this:

```
<form:input type="text" name="emergencyComplaint" id="emergencyComplaint" path="emergencyComplaint" />
```

I do not have OneToMany example handy but I think you are smart enough to identify the issue by now while reading this. If not then to get an idea, take a look at [this](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/userregistration.jsp) and [this](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/model/AppUser.java).

Comment: Its is working fine now but only for one attribute, when i comment emergencyComplaint inputs, it takes in status. But when i try to send both of them together it does not.

Comment: What error you are getting now? Share full error trace.